# Do we have any option of adding suppliers and suppliers information in the admin?

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm new to magento. I need to add suppliers along with our products and the supplier information should also be editable. Please suggest me how can i do this.
I'm using Magento 1.7

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default magento not provide this functionality, but still you can do this using magento attribute.

Create one attribute "supplier or something" and assigned this newly created attribute to Attribute Set of magento, now this newly created attribute is display in your product edit page.

If you are new to magento this link might be useful to you [How to create attribute?](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields)

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested you can but it is a slow process. What the larger companies use is an external MDM or PIM to maintain the data in a more efficient way which connects to the eCommerce Platform (Magento). It is obviously more complex but you can maintain 5-10x more products as the MDM/PIM is much more efficient at the data manipulation, unfortunatley it is also very complex to do. We normally intergrate some third party configured solutions for this, if it is simple the Magento attributes are the way to go but you will find the data manipulation is time consuming.